# How to set custom (RGB) color to Navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I cannot to set my RGB color to `UINavigationBar`and ToolBar. I tried it

```
  let myColor = UIColor(red: 47, green: 206, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0)
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = myColor
  self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = myColor
```

Also I tried HSB color

```
let secondColor = UIColor(hue: 194, saturation: 82, brightness: 100, alpha: 1.0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = secondColor
self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = secondColor
```

But when I wrote the following method it works.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

How can I set my RGB color to bars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let myColor = UIColor(red: 47, green: 206, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0)
```

is incorrect. `UIColor` requires color components in a range `0.0 ... 1.0`. So you probably need

```
let myColor = UIColor(red: 47.0/255.0, green: 206.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

From the [UIColor docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 73.0 / 255.0, green: 155.0 / 255.0, blue: 255.0/ 255.0, alpha: 1.0)